# How to Handle validation within a custom TextBox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've got a custom TextBox to handle measurements (feet, inches, mm) that has a couple Dependency Properties that determine what the formatting of the box should be when the box loses focus. I got all the conversions happening in the `OnLostFocus` function because conversions mid-input would not work. In `OnLostFocus`, I convert the value to a number depending on some other DP properties and set a Measurement property. All this works great.

My question is, how do I handle validation? When someone inputs an invalid value, I want the textbox to go red, much like you could do with a Binding that has `ValidatesOnExceptions=true`. I tried something like below in the catch block of OnLostfocus

```
    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text))
            {
                Text = "0";
            }
            if (IsMetric)
            {
                var measurement = convertStuffHere();
                Text = measurement.Text;
                Measurement = measurement.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                var measurement = convertOtherStuffHere();
                // convert and formatting stuff here...

                Text = measurement.Text;
                Measurement = measurement.Value;
            }

            var binding = this.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            if (binding != null)
                Validation.ClearInvalid(this.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty));

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            var rule = new DataErrorValidationRule();
            var binding = this.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            if (binding != null)
            {

                ValidationError validationError = new ValidationError(rule, this.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty));

                validationError.ErrorContent = "This is not a valid input";

                Validation.MarkInvalid(this.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty), validationError);
            }


        }
        finally
        {
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
        }
    }
```

This almost works, but the validation error shows up late. I have to lose focus, get focus, and lose focus again before a red box shows around the textbox.

I'm using it like `<myns:MeasurementTextBox Text="{Binding MeasurementText1, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Margin="10" IsMetric="True"></myns:MeasurementTextBox>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TextBoxBase.TextChanged event instead of UIElement.LostFocus.

Comment: Ahah. This worked. I ended up parsing the value in TextChanged and then formatting in lost focus. I was worried doing it in TextChanged would force the binding to update every time input was typed (I wanted it on LostFocus), but I guess the UpdateSourceTrigger is there for controlling that. Thanks!